# Wireless network unavailable, no networks found after Windows update

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, .net-framework, service-pack

Old Dell Inspiron 8200 laptop with Linksys Wireless G network adapter card (WPC54G v2).  Wireless connection was working fine.  Then I ran a bunch of windows updates, I think the last one was the recent .NET 3.5 service pack update.

Now wireless networks won't connect.  Using windows to manage wireless, no networks show up.  I'm typing right now on another laptop where wireless is working fine. I've restarted router & Dell laptop several times.  Tried to Repair wireless connection and refresh network list.  Also restarted DHCP and WZC service, all to no avail.

I then uninstalled .NET 3.5 SP (don't remember number) and .NET 3.0 SP2.  I don't remember all the windows updates that I just ran because I haven't used this laptop in a while so had to catch up on some updates.

Comment: i doubt the .net updates have anything to do with it.  might have been one of the earlier updates, though.  did you let it install SP3 or IE8?

Answer (score 1):

Tried a system restore? and then manually update one by one to see which one caused it or better look into which could cause the problem?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084

Answer (score 0):

Realized I hadn't rebooted after uninstalling .Net 3.0 SP2, so I rebooted and the network is now working.  So I think that was it but can't say for sure.  When I go to Windows update now it tells me I need Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 and .NET Framework 3.5 Family Update for .NET versions 2.0 through 3.5.  I'm not sure if that comprises both of the things I uninstalled.

*Update: Later on wireless network stopped working again.  Gave up and went to the basement to tie in directly to the router.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of the windows updates might have been a driver for your wireless adapter.  Have you tried rolling back the driver?